# Loading external file as resource

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am loading resource files like following

```
public static JSONArray readConfig(String fileName) throws IOException, JSONException{
    ClassPathResource res = new ClassPathResource(fileName);    
    byte[] bdata = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(res.getInputStream());
    String json = new String(bdata, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(json);
    return jarr;
};
```

I would like to know if its possible to add an external location/file like "/something/something1/config.json" to the resources/classpath so that it can be read by the same code as above.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the folder location in the classpath.

```
java -Dloader.path="/something/something1/" -jar your-app.jar
```

see [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html#executable-jar-property-launcher-features) for `loader.path` documentation

If you want to load a resource that is not in the classpath, use `FileSystemResource` instead of `ClassPathResource` so it will load the resource in the file system.

Comment: is it possible to do it from the code it self, like when we are creating our app?

Comment: Doing so is like hard-coding the path in your application. What if the path has changed or different in the environment from where you deployed your application. In that case you have to repackage your application because of the change in the path. Another way is you can use external property file where you define the location of /something/something1/config.json.

Comment: actually the path is in an env var so hard coding is not an issue. I just need to reuse the existing code to fetch the external file as well.

Comment: Then it's okay.. you can have an overloaded method of the code above that loads a file using FileSystemResource and the argument is the path from env variable.

Comment: Can u plz update ur ans with FileSystemResource so that i can mark it as ans...

Comment: @NikhilGupta updated with option to use FileSystemResource